# Is there a way to proof why prices non-negative or strictly positive in some cases?

Tags: consumer-theory, production-function, general-equilibrium

I am studying Microeconomics at a Graduate level with Mas-Colell and I found something in our course slides that I do not know how to prove:

- If we allow free disposal in the production set, the vector of prices will have to be non-negative (to avoid infinite profits).
- If "all commodities are productive (can be used as inputs directly or indirectly)", the vector of prices will have to be strictly positive.
- If a good is preferred in some way, its price will be positive.

Is there a way to proof these statements formally? I can understand the intuition, but a proof will make me more assured of them.

Comment: Can you please make your question more precise? Clearly, you are talking about the equilibrium price of some economy, but what are the exact assumptions you make about this economy?

Comment: A General Equilibrium for a Production Economy. Just any set of standard simple assumptions that you might see fit, since the statements should hold in any standard case: Functions are well defined, Consumers have some endowment, Production can be DRS or CRS, etc. And thank you!